# How to prevent Azure CDN bandwidth abuse by malicious bandwidth-vampire requests?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Just to let folks know, I did edit the post slightly as some people have suggested, and the question has been posted on Azure CDN forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9e37ca24-b38d-4193-847b-f679eab76aa5/azure-cdn-bandwidth-abuse-by-malicious-bandwidth-vampire-requests?forum=azurecdn). The reason I am posting it on StackOverflow as well, is to try and reach a bigger audience in hope that folks that have dealt with the same/similar issue could provide valuable solutions/feedback. As far as I know there's currently no solution to this problem, yet it's something that affects any business that uses CDN to deliver their content. I am open to editing this question further, but what I would ask, is that folks don't simply down-vote this question because it sounds like a "rant", it's not, and I can guarantee you that it affects thousands of businesses out there and costs people thousands of dollars a year whether they are aware of it or not.

So here's the situation. Let's say that I am building a picture gallery website and I would like to use Azure CDN to deliver my content for me. In the backend, Azure CDN will pull content from an Azure storage account. CDN is fast and powerful, but it seems though it can be a little unsecured in terms of preventing someone from being able to pull content in very large quantities and thus leaving a user with a huge bandwidth bill. Let me demonstrate what I mean.

So last night I decided to write a simple console app that would download a simple image from my future to be picture gallery website, in a for{} loop, the code is below:

```
namespace RefererSpoofer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;

            for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
            {
                string myUri = "http://myazurecdnendpoint.azureedge.net/mystoragecontainer/DSC00580_1536x1152.jpg";
                myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(myUri);
                myHttpWebRequest.Referer = "www.mywebsite.com";

                myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                Stream response = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response);

                Image image = Image.FromStream(streamReader.BaseStream);

                image.Save(string.Format("D:\\Downloads\\image{0}.Jpeg", x), ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                myHttpWebResponse.Close();
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This console application makes 1000 super-fast continuous requests to an image file that is hosted on my Azure CDN endpoint, and saves them to 'D:\Downloads' folder on my PC, with each filename corresponding to the for{} loop iteration, i.e. image1.jpeg, image2.jpeg, etc.

So what just happened? In about 1 minute of time, I have cost myself 140MB of bandwidth. With this being a Premium CDN, priced at $0.17/GB, let's do the math together:  0.14GB * 60minutes * 24hours * 30days * 0.17cents/GB = $1028.16 of bandwidth costs just if someone (a competitor for example) wanted to make a single request for a single image for a duration of the month to jeopardize my website. I think you guys can see where I am going with this...my website will have thousands of images, in hi-res, btw, the image that I was using in this example was a mere 140KB in size. These types of requests can come from anonymous proxies, etc.

So the question that I have is: What can one do to prevent someone from abusing a publicly exposed CDN endpoint? Obviously one can't be stuck paying $5,000, $20,000 for bandwidth resulting from malicious requests.

Now Azure Premium CDN has an advanced Rules Engine, that can filter out requests based on Referer, and respond with a 403 error in case the Referer doesn't match your website. But, the Referer can be faked, as I did in the above code sample, and CDN still allows the requests to be served (I tested with a Referer spoof). This sucks, a lot of people use Refer to prevent 'hotlinking', but in this case of bandwidth abuse, what does it matter if Referer can be faked with just a line of code?

***A couple of ideas that I've had in regards to preventing such abuse and huge bandwidth cost:***

*Both solutions would require an action from CDN:

1. When a request comes for content to the CDN, CDN could make a call to the client server passing in a) IP address of the user b) the CDN Uri requested. And then the client server would check how many times the Uri was requested from this particular IP, and if the client logic sees that it was requested let's say 100 times over the past minute, then obviously this would signal abuse, because browsers cache images, while malicious requests don't. So the client machine would simply reply 'false' to serving the content for this particular request. This would not be a perfect solution since the additional callback to client infrastructure would cause a small delay, yet it's definitely better than being potentially stuck with a bill that would look like the amount of money you have saved up in your bank's savings account.
2. *A better solution.* Built in a limit for number of times a file can be served over CDN within a particular time frame, per ip. For example, in the example of the image file above, if one could configure the CDN to serve no more than let's say 50 image requests / IP / within 10 minute time frame. If the abuse was detected, then CDN could, for a time defined by a customer a) serve a 403 for a particular abused uri. or b) server 403 for all uri's if the request is coming from an abuser IP. All times / options should be left configurable to the customer. This would definitely help. There's no callback here which saves time. The downside is that CDN will have to keep track of Uri/IP address/ Hit count.

***Which solutions would NOT work:***

1. Signed URL's won't work because the signature query string parameter would be different every time and browsers would constantly make requests for data, effectively wiping out browser cache for images.
2. Having a SAS access signature for azure blob would not work either because a) Uri is different every time b) There's no limit on how many times you can request a blob once SAS is granted. So abuse scenario is still possible.
3. Checking your logs and simply banning by IP. I was testing this type of abuse via anonymous proxy yesterday and it worked like a charm. Switched IPs in a matter of seconds and continued abuse (of my own content) for testing purposes. So this is out as well, unless one has a nanny to monitor the logs.

***Solutions that can work, but are not feasible:***

1. Filter requests on your web server. Sure, this would be the best way to control the issue and track the number of requests / IP, and simply not serve the content when abuse is detected. But then you loose the big benefit of not delivering your content over super-fast, proximity-to-client optimized CDN. Besides the fact that your servers will be slowed down a lot by serving out large byte content such as images.
2. Simply bite the bullet and not worry about it. Well...then you know that the pothole that will take your wheel out is just down the road, so no, it's not a comfortable feeling to go with this option.

With all of the above said, the Premium CDN offering from Azure with custom Rules Engine might offer a solution somewhere in there, but with a very poor documentation and a lack of examples one only would have to guess how to properly protect yourself, so that's why I am writing this post. Has anyone ever tackled such an issue? and how would one solve it?

Any suggestions are appreciated, I am very open minded on the issue.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Although a very interesting question, it sounds like a rant and will likely be downvoted.  I suggest you edit it a little bit.  Azure product feedback can be sent here: https://feedback.azure.com

Comment: I'm upvoting it because I can clearly see the issue at hand. I think anyone who has experience in it would be able to reply with their advice. I do agree it could be narrowed down just to the issue though.

Comment: This isn't a CDN problem, if you host the same site on storage or azure websites, you pay as well for all downloads. Same problem there.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: I am a CDN Developer and this question came into my mind but i really don't know any way to prevent such abuse. Even if you could limit the requests/min/ip, if the files are very large, you got the same problem. I think the CDN should analyse what the behaviour of a "normal" user is and then filter

Comment: This issue arises regardless of how large/small the files are. It appears that Amazon has thought of that, I'll have to takea closer look at this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-rate-based-blocking.html

Answer (score -1):

This is theoretical because we don't serve our "app", yet but will likely soon face this problem:

Couldn't you just issue a cookie which expires very quickly (10 sec!?) on your site itself and check for that , using the Azure [standard rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine-match-conditions#request-cookies).

Then, on your "main site" you can have a custom check, that blocks IPs (or doesn't issue the cookie, respectively) if the IP exceeds a "reasonable" amout of requests.
Some preconditions:

- You probably would have to have more control over the "main site" that issues the cookie than you have via CDN. Don't know, if you can "channel" these requests directly to the "client server".
- The cookie has to be HttpOnly to not be faked from the client.

... Did I miss something?